# How can I determine which ingress controllers are configured on Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

Is there a command I can run or is there some way to identify whether a cluster has one or more ingress controllers configured?

I'm not asking about the actual ingresses themselves (which I know can be found with `kubectl get ingress --all-namespaces`).

Comment: Have you checked my answer? It helped you?

Answer (score 3):

There is no fancy way to achieve what you need. These two commands can help you and it really depends on what you need to choose between them.

```
$ kubectl get pods --all-namespaces -o=jsonpath='{range .items[*]}{"\n"}{.metadata.name}{":\t"}{range .metadata}{.labels}{", "}{end}{end}' | grep ingress | grep controller
```

```
$ kubectl get pods --show-labels --all-namespaces  | grep ingress | grep controller
```

Both commands are similar but with different outputs.

These commands are based on this [documation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/cheatsheet/) page.

Answer (score 2):

This command lists the ingress controllers:

```
$ kubectl get ingressclasses.networking.k8s.io
NAME    CONTROLLER             PARAMETERS   AGE
nginx   k8s.io/ingress-nginx   <none>       49d
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no specific way since an ingress controller is really just a daemon that talks to the kubernetes API. There is no centralized registration for them. You can start from `kubectl get pods --all-namespaces` and compare against the names of known controllers.

Answer (score 0):

As each IngressController needs the privilege to access Ingresses, we can find out all Roles and ClusterRoles which could access Ingress, and then RoleBindings/ClusterRoleBindings, associated ServiceAccounts, finally get all Pods using those ServiceAccounts.

Answer (score -2):

You can list all ingress controller pod by using selector. For example

```
kubectl get pods --all-namespaces --selector app=nginx-ingress,component=controller
```

Comment: That would only show pods for the ingress-nginx controller, not all controllers. And that's mostly up to how you deployed it.